# Django Form inheritance problem

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Why can't I do this?

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super (UserProfileConfig,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.tester = 'asdf'

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100,initial=self.tester)
```

More specifically, why cant the forms.CharField grab the variable tester that I set during construction?

I feel like I am missing something about the way Python handles this sort of thing...

*edit* :

What I am actually trying to do is this:

```
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super (UserProfileConfig,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.tester = request.session['some_var']

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100,initial=self.tester)
```

In other words, I need to grab a session variable and then set it to an initial value...

Is there any way to handle this through the __init__ or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got doesn't work because your `CharField` gets created, and pointed to by `UserProfileConfig.username` when the class is created, not when the instance is created.  `self.tester` doesn't exist until you call `__init__` at instance creation time.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344994/extra-parameter-for-django-models)

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100,initial=self.tester)
    tester = 'asdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:-

```
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100)


def view(request):
    user_form = UserProfileConfig(initial={'username': request.session['username',})
```

Which is the generally accepted method, but you can also do this:-

```
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super (UserProfileConfig,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'] = request.session['some_var']


    username = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100)


def view(request):
    user_form = UserProfileConfig(request=request)
```